# How to set users' all privileges to a path using asp.net C#?

Tags: asp.net

How can I authorize the users' all privileges to a path in a asp.net web app?
Just like the operation that I right-click a path, set users' all privileges in the security tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo myDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\foo");
System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity myDirectorySecurity = myDirectoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
string User = System.Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + "JohnDoe";
myDirectorySecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(User, FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
myDirectoryInfo.SetAccessControl(myDirectorySecurity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose as long as the user that the ASP.NET application runs as has appropriate file system permissions, this would work:

```
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Some\Path");
DirectorySecurity security = directory.GetAccessControl();
security.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
directory.SetAccessControl(security);
```